# Populate DropDownList from Azure Database in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I am still new to MVC and working my way around it. I need to get the "name" column of my district table into a dropdownlist to be able to pick from different Districts. The end game is that the user will pick a District from the dropdownlist and then be directed to a page where a list of schools(in a different table) will be shown with the selected district (i think that would be a query on the database using the value given from the dropdownlist). Basically what I have done so far is:

- Create an MVC Application.
- Create a Entity Framework Model.

[image]

- Create an empty controller.

[image]

- Create a view model(since every tutorial/ site answer has said to do
  so)

[image]

- Create a view.

[image]

I replicate step by step what these tutorials are telling me to do, but I get a different result. My dropdownlist gives me this outcome:

[image]

I need help sorting out what could be going wrong and why the data is not showing up in my dropdownlist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try I believe you are using the wrong SelectList constructor.  Assuming you want the value of the drop down list to be the "leaID" property

```
@Html.DropDownList("myList", new SelectList(ViewBag.districts, "leaId", "name")
```

I would however, approach it another way which will keep it mostly strongly typed:

```
public class DistrictViewModel
{
    public string SelectedDistrictId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Districts { get; set; }
}
```

Action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new DistrictViewModel() 
    {
        Districts = new SelectList(db.Districts.ToList(), "leaID", "name")
    }
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

cshtml:

```
@model DistrictViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedDistrictId, Model.Districts)
```

Comment: should be `@Html.DropDownList("myList", new SelectList(ViewBag.districts,"leaID", "name",_defaultvalue_)` instead with defaultvalue as optional

Comment: I tried using your code and it gave me all the leaID's so I figured, hm, what would happen if i did `ViewBag.districts, "name", "name"` and it oddly worked!

Comment: @Seichi after figuring it out, I refreshed to see your comment. So I changed it to your version and it works perfectly!

Comment: nice to hear that, now that the answer is updated, make sure to mark it as the right answer.

Comment: @Seichi, one more question. Would you happen to know how to store into a variable the district they pick from the list so i can use it in a query on the database, then show a page with the query result in a table?

Comment: It my answer it will store the selected value in the SelectedDistrictId value. then POST the form to an another action with the DistrictViewModel as the parameter.  That action should have the value in the SelectedDistrictId property.   From there you can serve a page or redirect or whatever you want to do.  (I would redirect)

Comment: @BrandonLumsden i posted an answer to this comment, hope it helps

Comment: `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedDistrictId, Model.Districts)`

this line gives the error:  `'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper <dynamic> has no applicable method named 'DropDownListFor' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.`

Comment: I would like to use your edited example, but what I posted comment wise yesterday is not working for me.

Comment: Make sure you put the @model DistrictViewModel at the top of your cshtml file.  Let me know if that helps

Comment: It didn't change anything. I saw that as a solution on multiple searches so I decided to try it but it's a no-go.

Comment: so I figured out that I had to use `@model SchoolView.Models.DistrictViewModel` instead of just `@model DistrictViewModel` so your code works! So with my other problem, when the first action result is done, does mvc move on to the next one? and I can pass the `SelectedDistrictId` to it as a param?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer to your comment using ajax

```
//Model
public class DistrictViewModel
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public SelectList District {get;set;}
    public int SelectedDistrict {get;set}
}


//Controller
public class DistrictController : Controller
{
 KUDEREntities db = new KUDEREntities();

 public ActionResult Index()
 {
    var model = new DistrictViewModel();
    model.Districts = db.Districts.ToList();
    model.SelectedDistrict=0;
    return view(model);
 }

 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Search(int id)
 {
    //do the search with the id of the selected district
    var data = db.Districts.Where(m=>m.leaId = id).FirstorDefault();//this would return the whole object.
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }   
}




//Index View
@Model DistrictViewModel

<div>
//with this your selector would be "#SelectedDistrict"
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.SelectedDistrict, new SelectList(Model.Districts,"leaId","name",Model.SelectedDistrict), new {@class=""})

//with this your selector would be "#myList"
//@Html.DropDownList("myList", new SelectList(ViewBag.districts, "leaId", "name", Model.SelectedDistrict)
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
//when you want to search for the id selected, you just need to call the Search function below
function Search() {
    //... now you have the value of the selecteditem 
    var parameters = { id: $("#SelectedDistrict").val() };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '@Url.Action("Search", "District")',
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "html",
        async: true,
        data: JSON.stringify(parameters),
        success: function (data) {
            //...do whatever with the data
        },
        failure: function (msg) {
            //... show a message of error
        }
    });
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't like this line:

`model.Districts = db.Districts.ToList();`

error:

`cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<SchoolView.Models.District> to System.Web.Mvc.SelectList`

Comment: try with somethign like this `model.Districts = new SelectList(
    db.Districts.AsEnumerable(), "leaID", "name");`

Comment: alright so it fixed that problem, but then it an error for this line: `model=>model.SelectedDistrict`

error:

`an expression tree may not contain a dynamic expression`

it seems like the initial answer is the only one that works so far, is there that big a difference between the initial & modified answers except that theres no viewbag?

I searched the error but i'm not getting much.

Comment: no big difference, i just write all that code to answer your comment in Mark Olsen answer and how you could use the selected item... Mark Olsen answer works for you. I wrote that code but didn't tested it couse don't have where to do it.

Comment: woah, so you wrote all that on the fly? that's awesome! thanks.